# SVG loses "pixel" when exporting - wrong export settings?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg, creative-cloud

I am working closely together with a developer to create websites. We've stumbled upon a problem when it comes to exporting SVGs from Adobe Illustrator (CC) and implementing them on websites.

The artboard in illustrator looks like follows:

[image]

Yet, when added to the web code, there is a gap we cannot get rid of:

[image]

SVG export settings age:

- styling: presentation attributes
- font: svg
- object ids: layer names
- decimal: 0

Additional option: responsive

Has anybody experienced anything similar?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Any shading / drop shadow on the shape?

Comment: You you *sure* the spacing is coming from the shape itself? not another element? or margin or padding or something? It could be rendering error if your SVG is not precise to the same, especially if it originally differs in dimensions. We need more detail (or the SVG itself)

Comment: There are no pixels in a SVG. Simply there are no guarantees that the anti aliasing and filling will work exactly the same on any other renderer. Since everything is done on each browser differently you either have to debug each SVG on every browser or be less control focused. Anyway im sure this case can be fixed with css.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Lucien!

No shading, no drop shadow. Just a plain shape :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Zach Saucier: No, I am not :) I'll have my developer double-check today. Dimensions and aspect ratios are the same. What do you mean by "if your SVG is not precise to the same"? You mean Illustrator export settings should match the attributes within the code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @joojaa - You are right. I'll talk to my developer and see if we can fix it with CSS.

Comment: Thanks again guys!

I'll post an update on our progress.

Comment: @NicoStrobl I mean that if the dimensions are different in your editor/viewer than the actual web page, there could potentially be rendering error if the positions are not precisely scalar (since everything is rendered to pixels and you can't have half of a pixel)

Comment: This shape really should be made in CSS unless it's to change size based on a percentage

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanks for clarifying. It's a responsive design element, scaling with in- and decreasing resolution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the svg is a different aspect ratio from the area it is intended to fit in.

For a shape as simple as a triangle in a box, I think the best solution is for your developer to use borders on a `::before` element to simulate a triangle shape. If the `::before` element is positioned to the center top of the box, then the aspect ratio of the box won't matter.

If you and the developer would rather use the svg, I would recommend trimming the artboard to the size of the svg, that way you don't have to worry about aspect ratios, the developer just has to set the svg to `height:100%` and center it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

We made sure the dimensions and aspect ratio are the same, but I'll check back with him and we'll look into this.

Excellent tip concerning trimming the SVG. This will be option number 2 for us to try.

I'll report back to update you on the results.

Comment: Setting the SVG to `height: 100%` would just make the SVG scale to the parent's height, not to the size of the artboard on which it's made

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the asset export feature in the newest version of Illustrator? It takes out a lot of guess work for getting SVG assets out of Illustrator.
It should not accidentaly crop out part of your art as long as you select it all and drag it into the asset export like shown below. I've had good luck with it recently.

[image]